What does "move an' gallang" mean?
Madonna's hairstylist is in Brazil, and she was sent a quite nonsensical mensage on her Instagram asking her to get vip accesses to the VIP area of Madonna's show. She then proceeded to reply: "(...) move an' gallang! I'm at work(...)".
Does the expression "move and gallang" mean "go away" or something like this?

Do you have a source where we can see what was said or did you hear this?  She could have said, Move on along, which can be understood as, Keep looking you won't find it [what you're looking for] here.

From the transcript of Youtube post GALANG|| What does that Jamaican word mean and how is it used?...

...the Jamaican word galang is said to be a contraction between the English words go along in English go along means a few things...

...it's got next to no currency among mainstream Anglophones, so I'd advise against using it yourself. I haven't bothered to watch the Youtube clip, but I assume in context it carries the relatively friendly implication Try somewhere else (Sorry, I can't help) rather than Get lost! (Be off with you!, to an older generation).

Apparently, Madonna likes Jamaica...

Madonna thanks Jamaica for making her 62nd birthday bash a memorable one: 'We will never forget you!'


Maybe just saying Jamaican English is enough.

@Lambie - or 'patois' as we say in the UK (that's the actual name used by Jamaicans). Sometimes written as 'patwah'. Weh yuh a seh? Mi deh try call yuh.

@MichaelHarvey Michael, my point is let's not otherize this. Why not direct your comment to our friend FF rather than to me?

Jamaican Patois or Patwah is generally reckoned an independent creole language so calling it "Jamaican English" is incorrect, although just "Jamaican" is probably OK in context.
